# Error in the imread after browsing the image in a global file_name variable

Tags: python, image, tkinter, imread

I created a simple user interface with tkinter that will allow the user to browse an image and when pressing the 'calculate angle' button it should print the angle between the 2 lines in the chosen image and print the value of the angle on the python console but I'm getting those errors:

```
File "D:\Python\PyFolder\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/PyCharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5/PyProjetcs/angelTest/tkTest.py", line 21, in calculate
    image = imread(file_name)
  File "D:\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\PyProjetcs\angelTest\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2152, in imread
    return matplotlib.image.imread(fname, format)
  File "D:\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\PyProjetcs\angelTest\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1369, in imread
    return handler(fname)
OSError: failed to read file
```

Here is my python code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import (hough_line, hough_line_peaks)
from pylab import imread


root = Tk()
root.geometry('270x250')
root.title("Angle Calculation")
root.iconbitmap(r'D:\\Pictures\\iconTest.ico')


def browse_file():
    global file_name
    file_name = filedialog.askopenfile()


def calculate():
    image = imread(file_name)
    image = np.mean(image, axis=2)

    h, theta, d = hough_line(image)

    angle = []
    dist = []

    for _, a, d in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
        angle.append(a)
        dist.append(d)

    angle = [a * 180 / np.pi for a in angle]
    angle_reel = np.max(angle) - np.min(angle)

    print(angle_reel)


btn1 = Button(root, command=browse_file, text='Browse Image').pack()

btn2 = Button(root, command=calculate, text='Calculate angle').pack()

label1 = Label(root, text='The angle is equal to:').pack()
text = Entry().pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone please explain to me where did I messed up and how to fix it please,and thank you.

Comment: first check `print(file_name)` before `imread()`. Next use this path to open file any other program or graphics editor. Maybe path is not correct or file is broken. Or you try to read file which is not image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be `askopenfile` which gives file object create with `open(selected_file)`.
You need `file_name.name` to get its name (as string).

Or use `askopenfilename` to get name instead of file object.

Comment: thank you,it did work when I used ```askopenfilename```